# Doing Ctrl-Alt-Break under BootCamp

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, boot-camp

When using the remote desktop client on Windows, one very useful keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-Alt-Break, which toggles the remote session between full screen and window.

How can I do the equivalent of Ctrl-Alt-Break on a MacBook Air keyboard when running Windows 7 under BootCamp?

Comment: I don't know, but Cmd-Alt-Break may be?
When you use Ctrl in Windows, use Cmd in Mac.

Comment: Actually, under BootCamp, Control is just Control. But the problem is more that the Mac keyboard doesn't have a 'break' key! :)

Comment: @Shouldn't it be one of the F# keys which are not there on windows keyboards? F13,F14 or F15, if you have them. My guess is on F14.

Comment: My MacBook air only has up to F12

Comment: So, `fn alt crtl shift f12` doesn't do it as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is possible, looking here 
http://noahcoad.com/post/211/get-back-missing-windows-keys-on-mac-keyboard

Ctrl-Alt-Fn-Esc will toggle fullscreen.

I've tried it and it works prefectly.

Comment: Wow, it does work! I wonder why. On regular PC keyboards, is there some combination that includes Esc? The only one I know of is Ctrl-Alt-Break.

Comment: One thing I haven't checked is whether this still works without the BootCamp keyboard drivers installed. I'll try and check this later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to put a close on this, it has now become pretty clear that there is no direct way to do it.

I even tried experimenting with autohotkey to remap a different combination into that, but I couldn't get it to work reliably. It worked to maximize the window, but then couldn't restore it since the remote desktop was then eating the keys (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

From a Magic Keyboard with enough F-keys, you can press `Ctrl+Option+F14`.

Comment: The question asks specifically about the MacBook Air keyboard, so this doesn't really answer the question.